# How do I set the Padding value to more than 8 in Sprite Atlass in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't set padding to more than 8. I'm useng Unity 2018.4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u9k9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google research gave me this thread:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/sprites-have-hairline-artifacts-when-using-spriteatlas-and-mipmapping-how-to-fix.713501/

And someone gave this custom script to set a custom padding value:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEditor;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.U2D;

using UnityEditor.U2D;

public class SpriteAtlasPaddingOverride

{

    [MenuItem("Assets/SpriteAtlas Set Padding 32")]

    public static void SpriteAtlasCustomPadding()

    {

        Object[] objs = Selection.objects;

        foreach (var obj in objs)

        {

            SpriteAtlas sa = obj as SpriteAtlas;

            if (sa)

            {

                var ps = sa.GetPackingSettings();

                ps.padding = 32;

                sa.SetPackingSettings(ps);

            }

        }

        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();

    }

}
```

Have a nice day.